# MYSQL, Duplicating records but changing a column's value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that duplicates all rows `WHERE employee = 16`(i.e.), but the new rows would have a different `employee` value.

Table before `INSERT`:

```
| employee | property_name | property_value |
|:--------:|:--------------|:---------------|
| 16       | Salary        | 28,000         |
| 16       | Department    | 12             |
| 17       | Salary        | 38,000         |
| 17       | Department    | 8              |
```

Desired outcome after `INSERT`:

```
| employee | property_name | property_value |
|:--------:|:--------------|:---------------|
| 16       | Salary        | 28,000         |
| 16       | Department    | 12             |
| 17       | Salary        | 38,000         |
| 17       | Department    | 8              |
| 18       | Salary        | 28,000         |
| 18       | Department    | 12             |
```

I've seen some threads that use variables. Could I set and reference a variable somehow that would replace values from an insert/select?

The [answer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/352585/1165832) looks like it would work. But I'd rather not create and drop tables like that.

Comment: You could use temporary tables, it's feels less painful.

Comment: That thread is about the case where you don't know in advance what columns the table has (because the poster didn't want to have to change the statement if the columns ever changed); but judging from your table design, that doesn't seem likely to a problem for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into YourTable (employee,property_name, property_value)
select 18, property_name, property_value from YourTable where employee = 16
```

Comment: Ha! Exactly what OP asked for, but I suspect not what's wanted.